# Segue not working when adding Class name to View Controller

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I’m having trouble figuring out what is wrong with my app. I created a “View Controller” that is embedded in a “Navigation Controller” with a “Sign Up” and a “Login” button that takes you to their respective "View Controllers". When I run Xcode with the Default Class it runs perfectly fine and takes you to their respective views. When I add the Custom class names the code runs but it doesn’t show the next page and just gives me this weird popup frame.

[image]

[image]

[image]

So that's what should happen but when I add the "Class" name for the View Controller the segue does something weird that looks like a popup but I have no idea why it's happening.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LhNTc.png)

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you show the code how your pushing the view controller?

Comment: That's the thing I don't even have any code written yet, all I did was connect them in the storyboard. "Sign Up" button being "Pushed" to the SignUpViewController, and "Login" being "Pushed" to the LoginViewController.

Comment: What do you have inside the SignUpViewController and LoginViewController is matters and the Storyboard of these screens should be designed respectively in order to see rendering properly.

Comment: @HarishSaran I've added 2 more screenshots of the SignUpViewController.swift file and the SignUpViewController connections.

Comment: I was able to run my test project without any glitches.. please try to create a new test project and see if that works...delete the old app from the device or simulator.

Comment: Why is your `SignUpViewController` a subclass of `UINavigationController`?

Comment: Ahhh okay, I have no idea why it's a subclass of UINavigationController. Thanks guys!

Comment: could you accept the answer @Erin?

Comment: @HarishSaran Sorry Harish, as you can tell I'm new to this lol. Just accepted your answer. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got your problem, why the super class of `SignUpViewController` is `UINavigationController`? make it to `UIViewController`.

Update your code in `SignUpViewController` and `LoginViewController` like below Screenshot,

[image]